# Should Kerberos cache file remain empty after successful authentication?

Tags: kerberos, cloudera-cdh

I'm struggling with connecting to Impala which is part of a kerberised CDH cluster via JDBC driver. For authentication I need to acquire a Kerberos ticket on my machine. `kinit` works like a charm. The strange is that, when I setup `KRB5CCNAME` variable pointing to a file the file remains empty after successful authentication, but `klist` shows that I'm authenticated. Is it the expected behaviour?

The reason I ask this is that, my java app can't connect to Impala and the error message suggest that the empty file could be the problem. However, a python script can connect to the same Impala from the same machine.

It is a Mac 2018.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It shouldn't.

Apple has its own bundled kerberos implementation (Heimdal) which does this strange empty file thing.

I installed `krb5` package from brew, modified the `PATH` accordingly and it works fine.

```
myself@mymachine:~$ brew info krb5
krb5: stable 1.16.2 (bottled) [keg-only]
Network authentication protocol
https://web.mit.edu/kerberos/
/usr/local/Cellar/krb5/1.16.2 (160 files, 3.7MB)
  Poured from bottle on 2018-12-18 at 15:20:46
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/krb5.rb
==> Dependencies
Required: openssl ✔
==> Caveats
krb5 is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /usr/local,
because macOS already provides this software and installing another version in
parallel can cause all kinds of trouble.

If you need to have krb5 first in your PATH run:
  echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/krb5/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
  echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/krb5/sbin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile

For compilers to find krb5 you may need to set:
  export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/krb5/lib"
  export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/krb5/include"

For pkg-config to find krb5 you may need to set:
  export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/krb5/lib/pkgconfig"

==> Analytics
install: 198 (30 days), 614 (90 days), 1,986 (365 days)
install_on_request: 182 (30 days), 557 (90 days), 1,768 (365 days)
build_error: 0 (30 days)

myself@mymachine:~$ /usr/bin/klist --version
klist (Heimdal 1.5.1apple1)
Copyright 1995-2011 Kungliga Tekniska Högskolan
Send bug-reports to heimdal-bugs@h5l.org
```

Similar issue will arise on Windows, where Kerberos does not respect whether KRB5CCNAME environment variable is set or not. The solution for this is using older version. [This page](https://www.simba.com/products/Impala/doc/ODBC_InstallGuide/win/content/odbc/hi/kerberos.htm) mentions 4.0.1 version, however on the Kerberos [page](https://web.mit.edu/kerberos/dist/) you can find 4.1. The first will use file cache, the latter will use API and pretty difficult to ask it not to use it.